# How to display all disk partitions on desktop

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, desktop, toolbar

on Mac OSX:

- Open Finder.
- Go to view menu - Show toolbar (if it is hidden in your finder)
- on the left top side you can see List of devices
- I have three disks over there.
- I want to add all those disk partitions on my desktop.

I don't know how; can someone show me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just go to Finder > Preferences

at General Tab > Show These Items on Desktop .. tick "Hard Disks"

then you'll see your hard disks on Desktop

[image]